# How-to access object in a stateful widget passed from MaterialPageRoute

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have a stateful widget as a details page in my flutter app:

```
class MyTestPage extends StatefulWidget {
    final Foo foo;
    MyTestPage({
      Key key,
      @required this.foo, }): super(key : key);
    @override
    MyTestPageState createState() => MyTestPageState();
}

class MyTestPageState extends State<MyTestPage> {
    Foo foo;
    @override
    void initState(){...}
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {...}
}
```

I'm passing a list item from my Home widget to `MyTestPage`. How do I access that variable (`foo`) from `MyTestPageState`?

My home widget contains a list, clicking on a `ListTile` takes you to a details widget for that `ListTile`. I'm using a `StatefulWidget` because I need to run a query against a Firebase Database on the details screen and I'm not sure how else to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a `State` subclass, use `widget` to refer to the `StatefulWidget`.

```
class MyTestPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Foo foo;

  MyTestPage({
    Key key,
    this.foo,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  MyTestPageState createState() => MyTestPageState();
}

class MyTestPageState extends State<MyTestPage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    print(widget.foo); // this is the Foo in MyTestPage
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {}
}
```